# Rounding asp.net chart series values

Tags: asp.net

I have below code

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
Chart1.Series["Available_Capacity(QTY)"].YValueMembers = Convert.ToString(dt.Columns[0]);
series.LabelFormat = "{0:#,#}";
```

The result is 1.671.197 however i would like to have 1,671

Answer (score 2):

```
Try series.LabelFormat = "{0:N0}";
```

BTW: you are not rounding, you are truncating, according to the desired output you said you wanted.

The `{0:N0}` format is simply discarding any decimal values. For example, to only get 2 decimal values, you'd do: `{0:N2}`

Comment: Exactly i would like to truncate it,basically  i put your code but it didnt work.before  series.LabelFormat = "{0:#,#}"  the result is 1671197 as i mentioned before i would like to have 1,67.Can you please assist?